# "value too long for type character varying(4)" even when string inputs appear to be less than 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to insert data with a Ruby on Rails app.  When attempting to save a model, I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(4)
```

I have triple-checked this data, and it's always less than four characters long when this happens.  There's only one 4-length field, `shape`, in the table so I'm pretty sure that's the field in question.  This is running in a rake task.

This looks like a simple "bad data, idiot" problem, but I just can't see what I'm missing.

**EDIT:**  The values shape is being set to are all coming from a fixed pool of predefined strings, all of which are two or three characters and use only upper-case, non-accented Latin letters.  Any object that isn't assigned one of these values is skipped over, with no `.save` call being made.

This is the table def for the model:

```
CREATE TABLE spree_diamonds
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  supplier_id integer,
  supplierlot character varying(48),
  certnum character varying,
  shape character varying(4),
  weight numeric(5,2),
  color integer,
  clarity integer,
  measure1 numeric,
  measure2 numeric(5,2),
  measure3 numeric(5,2),
  depth numeric(4,1),
  tablep integer,
  cut integer,
  lab character varying(8),
  cost numeric(9,2),
  price numeric(9,2),
  costct numeric(9,2),
  pricect numeric(9,2),
  canadamark character varying(32),
  girdlemin integer,
  girdlemax integer,
  girdlefinish character varying,
  polish integer,
  symmetry integer,
  fluor integer,
  fluorcolor character varying(16),
  crownangle numeric(4,1),
  crownheight numeric(4,1),
  pavilionangle numeric(4,1),
  paviliondepth numeric(4,1),
  comments character varying,
  certurl character varying,
  photourl1 character varying,
  photourl2 character varying,
  photourl3 character varying,
  photourl4 character varying,
  photourl5 character varying,
  videourl character varying,
  cert_dl_failed timestamp without time zone,
  photo_dl_failed timestamp without time zone,
  updated boolean,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  culet character varying,
  ratio numeric(4,1),
  product_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT spree_diamonds_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_rails_5aa48b1c15 FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
      REFERENCES spree_products (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

This an example of a .inspect call made on an object that generated this error.  There are hundreds more similar examples:

```
#<Spree::Diamond id: nil,
supplier_id: 221,
supplierlot: "KJ105084",
certnum: "5176224552",
shape: "RB",
weight: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebd1d10, '0.8E0',9(18)>,
color: 21,
clarity: 5,
measure1: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebd1220, '0.586E1',18(18)>,
measure2: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebd0f28, '0.591E1',18(18)>,
measure3: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebd0c58, '0.367E1',18(18)>,
depth: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebd09b0, '0.624E2',18(18)>,
tablep: 58,
cut: 6,
lab: "GIA",
cost: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebcbb18, '0.283968E4',18(36)>,
price: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebc0b00, '0.3266E4',9(27)>,
costct: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebcbd70, '0.35496E4',18(18)>,
pricect: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebc0970, '0.40825E4',18(36)>,
rapprice: nil,
canadamark: nil,
girdlemin: 6,
girdlemax: 6,
girdlefinish: "Faceted",
culet: 0,
polish: 4,
symmetry: 4,
fluor: 6,
fluorcolor: nil,
crownangle: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebb9a08, '0.36E2',9(18)>,
crownheight: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebb9788, '0.155E2',18(18)>,
pavilionangle: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebb9d28, '0.406E2',18(18)>,
paviliondepth: nil,
comment: nil,
certurl: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/rap.certs/gia/Certificates...",
photourl1: "http://certs.rapnet.com/userfolders/77165/Images/",
photourl2: nil,
photourl3: nil,
photourl4: nil,
photourl5: nil,
videourl: nil,
cert_dl_failed: nil,
photo_dl_failed: nil,
updated: true,
created_at: "2015-09-24 23:45:51",
updated_at: "2015-09-24 23:45:51",
ratio: #<BigDecimal:7fd16ebb2eb0, '0.1008532423 2081911262 79863481E1',36(45)>,
product_id: nil>
```

This is the complete error message I'm getting:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR:  value too
 long for type character varying(4)
: INSERT INTO "spree_diamonds" ("supplier_id", "supplierlot", "certnum", "shape"
, "weight", "color", "clarity", "measure1", "measure2", "measure3", "depth", "ta
blep", "lab", "certurl", "photourl1", "costct", "cost", "price", "pricect", "pol
ish", "symmetry", "fluor", "girdlemin", "girdlemax", "girdlefinish", "culet", "p
avilionangle", "paviliondepth", "crownangle", "crownheight", "ratio", "cut", "up
dated", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9,
$10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25,
$26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35) RETURNING "id"
```

Comment: Try a trim,  just in case some invisible character is coming through, although it doesn't look like it. Also make sure the bindings are correct. Also check the current DB schema,  not just the definition.

Comment: Do you have any special characters? Is it possible that the length is the number of character bytes the field can contain, and therefore as some characters (letters with accents) will take up two bytes, you can't always assume four characters will fit.

Comment: The values `shape` is being set to are all coming from a fixed pool of predefined strings, all of which are two or three characters and use only upper-case, non-accented Latin letters.